# How to extend this regex to match this mask?

Tags: javascript, regex, formatting

I have found the following solution for adding dashes after every 4th character:

```
$('.number_to_format').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join("");
  if (foo.length > 0) {
      foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

But I have a more difficult problem to solve, my input should match exactly this format as I type numbers:

99999999-9-99

So put dash after the 8th and 9th character automatically.

I have tried the jQuery masking plugins already, but I want the solution without plugins.

How should I extend the regex above to get this working? Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output for `99999999-9-99`?

Comment: As I'm typing in the input, it adds the dashes automatically, just like e.g. a Windows serial number field.

Sorry, but foo.replace(/^(.{8})(.)/, "$1-$2-") didn't do the job but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

(The output will be 99999999-9-99)

```
<input type="text"  id="data">

$(document).ready(function ()
$('#data').keyup(function () {
    var x = $(this).val();
    console.dir(x);
    x = x.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
    if (x.length > 9) x = x.replace(/(\d{8})(\d)(\d+)/, '$1-$2-$3');
    else if (x.length > 8) x = x.replace(/(\d{8})(\d+)/, '$1-$2');
    else x = x;
    $(this).val(x);
});
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/tzob1e7a/3/)